# How to force the re-login to all users when roles are changed using Symfony2 and FOSUserBundle?

Tags: symfony, fosuserbundle

I have a question about how can I force a re-login for all users when I execute a process that reloads all user roles.

Is possible do that? I'm using FOSUserBundle as user provider.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I never used `FosUserBundle` but one simple way to do this is in your [User Class](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/security/custom_provider.html#create-a-user-class) implementing the [EquatableInterface](http://api.symfony.com/2.7/Symfony/Component/Security/Core/User/EquatableInterface.html) and inserting in the `isEqualTo` method something like:

```
# this comparison is ONLY indicative 

if ($this->roles !== $user->getRoles()) { 
    return false;
}
```

PS: At any request Symfony checks that assigned roles are not changed (but you can add also other fields to check like Email, Username, etc...), otherwise the user is automatically disconnected (but without printing a friendly message to the user)

Comment: It seems that works. I gonna try a little more, but seems ok! Thank you!

Comment: @David Glad to be helpful. Let me know.